# What is the number of processes in Laravel Horizon I should use?

Tags: laravel

I have installed [Laravel Horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/horizon) to mange my queues, and inside the published config there are these settings:

```
'local' => [
    'supervisor-1' => [
        'connection' => 'redis',
        'queue' => ['default'],
        'balance' => 'simple',
        'processes' => 3,
        'tries' => 3,
    ],
],
```

In the `processes` setting:

- How can I determine the number of processes I should use in a real
  world app?
- Is there a limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a guess until your application is in the real world. You need to balance acceptable wait times for jobs to kick off with projections on how often jobs will be scheduled and how long they will take to run.  A reasonable upper limit is going to be heavily dependent on the hardware you're running on and the overall server workload.

It's probably not worth spending too much time on this ahead of time vs monitoring it and dialing it in as you get up and running.

Comment: let's say I have a queue called "verfyEmailQueue" inside the queue setting, which will send an email email verification (using mailgun for example) to the user's email when a user is registered in the website. How can I guess the number of processes?

Comment: How many sign ups do you anticipate getting per minute?  How long will it take to process the job (send the verify email) and how long is the acceptable wait time for a user to receive a confirmation email?  I'm going to guess 1 process would be fine for that queue as it doesn't take long to send an email.  If you start getting a hundred signups per minute, reevaluate then.